# Implicit conversion when an array is involved

Tags: c#, .net, operator-keyword, implicit-conversion

I have a CompanyLegacy class that I would like to convert to CompanyNew class. 
Here are my classes.

```
public class CompanyLegacy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person[] Persons { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator CompanyNew(CompanyLegacy setting)
    {
        // How to convert Persons[] to Employee[]
    }
}

public class CompanyNew
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Employee[] Employees { get; set; }

}

public class Employee
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Employee(Person p)
    {
        return new Employee()
        {
            LastName = p.LastName,
            FirstName = p.FirstName
        };
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to have a method call as simple as below for doing the conversion.

static CompanyNew GetCompany(CompanyLegacy company)
        {
            CompanyNew newCompany = company;
            return newCompany;
        }

As you can see I am trying to use implicit operators for doing the conversion. However I am not sure how can I use the implicit operator within CompanyLegacy for converting the Person[] to an Employee[] even though I can convert a Person to an Employee.

Comment: `Employees = setting.Persons.Select(p => (Employee)p).ToArray();`